# how to iterate dataframes where name types in list are strings

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, iteration

I have a list which includes dataframe names

```
abc=list(dictfortoday.keys())
print(abc)
```

Output:

```
['portfel0','portfel1','portfel2']
```

And all items in list is dataframe

I want to iterate them as below

```
for i in abc:
    df['COLUMN'].isin([i['capital']])
```

Comment: why did you mess up with the edit? Now the code is not well printed

Comment: use `for i in abc: df['COLUMN'].isin([globals()[i]['capital']])`

Comment: Although it is good to have the dataframes in the list and not just the names. or have them in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in abc: 
  df['COLUMN'].isin([globals()[i]['capital']])
```

Note that this is not a good way to solve the problem at hand. It is just a work around. You should consider having the dataframes in a list/dictionary if you are going to perform the same operations on them